# How to access method of class stored in std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml, variant

I am trying to access method of class held in std::variant. Unfortunately it throws and following error:

```
class ’std::variant<A, int>’ has no member named ‘function’
```

Code:

```
class A {
private:
    int number = 0;
public:
    A() {};
    void function(int i) {
        number += i;
    }
};

// ... main ...
std::variant<A,B> array[4][4];

array[0][0] = A(){};
array[0][0].function(3);
```

I tried to read documentation however I still don't understand how or whether should I use std::get() and std::variants.index() to access the aforementioned method.

After some reading I tried doing something like this in loop:

```
std::size_t t=array[i][j].index();
std::get<t>(array[i][j]).function();
```

It still didn't work though. The error was:

```
note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class ... _Types> constexpr _Tp&& std::get(std::variant<_Types ...>&&)
     constexpr inline _Tp&& get(variant<_Types...>&& __v)

template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use `std::get`.

Comment: The active type of the variant is a runtime property, so one cannot directly invoke member functions on the variant and expect them to be forwarded to the active member, because such invocation is a compile-time thing.

Comment: Looks to me like you're attempting to learn how to use variants without [helpful assistance from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which should have many examples of how to set and access members of variants. This is basic variant usage that I expect to be covered in every C++ textbook. Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a very efficient replacement for a textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize a value in `std::variant` you can use `std::get`, or since C++17, [`emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace):

```
array[0][0].emplace<A>();
```

To access a value, use [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get):

```
std::get<A>(array[0][0]).function(3);
```

---

In addition, the template argument of `std::get` must be known at compile-time, so `std::get<t>` when `t` is a variable, won't work. You can do it slightly differently, e.g. like this:

```
std::size_t t = array[0][0].index();
switch (t) {
case 0:
    std::get<0>(array[0][0]).function(3);
case 1:
    // . . .
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some new problem with it, explained in edited version.

Comment: why switch on the index instead of `visit`?

Answer (score 1):

[std::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) is the solution you are looking for.

```
std::get<A>(array[0][0]) = AA();
std::get<A>(array[0][0]).function(3);
```

Or

```
std::get<int>(array[0][0]) = 56;
```

One more thing, you can use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead this `C` array, and to get more standard library functionality:

```
std::array<std::array<std::variant<A,int>, 4>, 4> array;
```

The usage can still be the same, or a little more safer:

```
std::get<A>(std::get<0>(std::get<0>(array))) = A();
```

Or:

```
std::get<A>(array.at(0).at(0)) = A();
```

The usage in this case of `operator[]` for the array might not throw an error in case of wrong index. You better use `.at()` function, that will throw an exception in case of out of range access:

```
try {
    std::get<A>(array.at(0).at(0)) = A();
} catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Read about [std::out_of_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

---

#### EDIT - template argument deduction/substitution failed

```
std::size_t t = array[i][j].index();
std::get<t>(array[i][j]).function(); // Error!
```

You cannot use non const value as template arguments. Template arguments are analyzed during the compilation time, and here `t` is known only at runtime. Please refer to the following question: [Trying to return the value from std::variant using std::visit and a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088928/trying-to-return-the-value-from-stdvariant-using-stdvisit-and-a-lambda-expre)

#### [Read more about variants](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/variant.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some new problem with it, explained in edited version.

Answer (score 1):

you call the get method giving as parameter the variant and specifying the class for the template

ex: suppose you have a point class with x,y coordinates
then std::get(v) will allow you to access the point in the variant

```
std::variant<int, Point> v;
v = 177;
int i = std::get<int>(v);
v = Point(15,18);

try 
{
  Point s = std::get<Point>(v);
  std::cout << s.getX();
}
catch (const std::bad_variant_access&) {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some new problem with it, explained in edited version.